# Proving that $[k[u]:k[u^l]]=1$ if $(l,[k[u]:k])=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I am trying to prove that $$[k[u]:k[u^l]]=1$$  if  $(l,[k[u]:k])=1$.

I do not know whether the above statement is true or false. Here $u$ is an algebraic number over the field $k$. But I was able to prove this in a very special case where $l$ is $2 $ and $[k[u]:k]$ is an odd integer. The method I used was $[k[u]:k[u^l]][k[u^l]:k]=[k[u]:k]$ and then I used the fact that $[k[u^l]:k] \geq n+1$. Now this sort of method is not generalising. If anyone can give any hints it would be great.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that to understand better the problem you have to edit some hypothesis. Who is $u$? what the meaning of $k[u]$? I think you have to explain  better your notation.

Comment: @JosephCurwen u is an algebraic number over k

Comment: @JosephCurwen i assumed that the notation was standard sorry

Comment: And $k[u]$? Has someting about polynomial valuated in u? Is a notation to indicate the smallest extension of $k$ that contains $u$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suppose that in your notation $k[u]$ is the smallest extension of $k$ wich contains $u$.
In my notation this field is $k(u)$

Now, in this hypothesis, the assert is actually FALSE.

Let $k$ be $\mathbb{Q}$ and consider $u=\zeta_{15}$, where $\zeta_{15}$ is a primitive rooth of $x^{15}-1$.

We have $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15}):\mathbb{Q}]=\varphi(15)=8$, so we can take $l=3$ but $\zeta_{15}^3$ is a primitive 5-th rooth of 1,  so a rooth of the polynomial $x^5-1$ and $$[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15}^3):\mathbb{Q}]=\varphi(5)=4 < [\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15}):\mathbb{Q}]=8$$

and finally we obtain $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15}):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15}^3)]=2$.